# error deserialisation graniteds amf object

Tags: hibernate, apache-flex, amf, graniteds

When deserialising as3 object to java . GraniteDS throw this Exeption :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet
```

I think some dependencies should been in pom.xml . any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

GraniteDS does not know anything about the hibernate/any pojos apart from the primitive types and collections when serializing/deserializing. So, in your case even though the library is in place `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` Granite does not look for it.

**Solution:**

> Create a copy of the hibernate objects for using int graniteDS, so you
>   will have one version for sending the AMF objects and other one
>   dealing with hibernate. Also, it is a good practice to have two
>   copies.

Comment: sorry , i didn't understand what you proposed . what do you mean by creating different copies ?

Comment: @SamiJmii Meaning, do not use the hibernate objects to send data to the UI. If you have Person object in Hibernate, create another object named Person in a different package but with same properties and use this object to send to the UI.

Comment: ok , but this throwble (classe not found ) occurs when i send data from flex client to the server . it occurs somehow when deserializing my 'person' data to it's corresponding java type . my person data does not even have any collection data just primitive types .

Answer (score 0):

After debugging , It seems  graniteDS (version : 3.1.0.GA) proposes this class as externalizer

```
org.granite.hibernate.HibernateExternalizer
```

wich depend on hibernate dependencies :

```
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentCollection;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSortedMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSortedSet;
```

those dependencies are ok in hibernate versions (3.X) . but the package namespace is no longer valide in hibernate 4 :

```
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag;
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentList;
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet;
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSortedMap;
import org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSortedSet;
```

as a work around : we could define our owen externalizer with the same implementation HibernateExternalizer and change  the imports . then we use this custom externalizer in granite-config.xml .

Hoping that graniteDS decouple there implementation from external dependencies that could make breaking change as below .